# Production build failing with plotly.js and ionic 3

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, plotly.js

I'm using plotly.js (@1.35.2) with types/plotly.js in Ionic (3.6.1).

When using `ionic serve` everything (including the plots) works fine in the browser. When using `ionic cordova run android --device`, it is working fine, too. The app is installed on the device and usable. But there is a long waiting time when starting the app.

When I try building the app for production with `ionic cordova run android --device` , I get errors and the build is not working at all. I assume it has something to do with the minify process used in production builds. I am not sure if I understand the errors correctly, either.

This is the error I get:

```
Error: ./node_modules/d3/d3.js
Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at checkPropertyAccessExpressionOrQualifiedName (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38454:62)
at checkPropertyAccessExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38413:20)
at checkExpressionWorker (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:41300:28)
at checkExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:41257:42)
at checkBinaryLikeExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40834:28)
at checkBinaryExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40827:20)
at checkExpressionWorker (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:41335:28)
at checkExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:41257:42)
at checkBinaryLikeExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40834:28)
at checkBinaryExpression (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40827:20)
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/src/plots/plots.js 9:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/src/transforms/groupby.js
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/lib/groupby.js
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/pages/statSites/statQuestionnaire/statQuestionnaire.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/plotly.js/src/plots/cartesian/axes.js
Module parse failed: Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: / newDiff + 1e-6) % 1 < 2e-6 &&(((newFirst - ax._forceTick0) /: Unmatched ')' (185:53)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         // and forceTick0 can be shifted to newFirst
|         if (function (ax, _minDtick) {
|             if (_minDtick === void 0) { _minDtick = / newDiff + 1e-6) % 1 < 2e-6 &&(((newFirst - ax._forceTick0) / newDiff % 1) +
|                 1.000001) % 1 < 2e-6; }
|             ax._minDtick = newDiff;
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/src/transforms/filter.js 11:11-45
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/lib/filter.js
 @ ./node_modules/plotly.js/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/pages/statSites/statQuestionnaire/statQuestionnaire.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
at BuildError.Error (native)
at new BuildError (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
at callback (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:119:28)
at emitRecords.err (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:265:13)
at Compiler.emitRecords (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:371:38)
at emitAssets.err (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:258:10)
at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:364:12)
at next (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/home/aiko/IdeaProjects/etmos_the/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
```